# How to print data from a row in R

Tags: r, excel, date, type-coercion

I want to print out all of the values in a row that correspond to a string in the first column. My `df` is as follows:

```
head(df)
Genes       WT250        WT50       WT10    WT250-50     WT50-10 WT250.50   WT50.10 WT250.50.5p WT250.50.5n WT50.10.5p
1 1-Mar  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0000000           0           0       NaN       NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN
2 1-Mar  0.00815513  0.00996992  0.0773793 -0.00181479 -0.06740938 0.8179735 0.1288448   0.8588721   0.7770748  0.1352870
3 2-Mar 28.69470000 24.85740000 23.5945000      3.8373      1.2629 1.1543725 1.0535252   1.2120912   1.0966539  1.1062014
4 2-Mar 22.89040000 27.83080000 36.7604000     -4.9404     -8.9296 0.8224844 0.7570864   0.8636087   0.7813602  0.7949408
5 3-Mar  0.98224300  1.32089000  1.2301800   -0.338647     0.09071 0.7436221 1.0737372   0.7808032   0.7064410  1.1274240
6 4-Mar  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0000000           0           0       NaN       NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN
WT50.10.5n
1        NaN
2  0.1224026
3  1.0008489
4  0.7192321
5  1.0200503
6        NaN
```

I want to print all of the values in the same row as the gene Ifng

Comment: Aah the good old [Excel-gene-to-date bug](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-016-1044-7); I haven't seen that one in a while. You might want to take a closer look at your source data. And I guess you're looking for `df[df$Genes == "Ifng", ]` provided your gene is labelled as `"Ifng"`; or perhaps `df[toupper(df$Genes) == "IFNG", ]`

Comment: I'm confused - I don't see the string `"Ifng"` anywhere in your data. It looks like your first column is a date? Can you clarify your goal? In general, if you want to print the `i`th row of a data frame, use `df[i, ]`. If you want to print the row(s) where column `"A"` has value `val`, use `df[df$A == val, ]`.

Comment: You'll see that I only printed out head(df) so that is only the first few rows of data. I have 23,000 rows so I would like to print of the row corresponding to Ifng so I don't have to sift through it myself.

Comment: @LizziDuncan In that case, the solutions Gregor and I give will work. But please *please* take a closer look at your data and the erroneous conversion of gene names to dates due to Excel!